# Image Column in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I create this such image column in windows form:[image]

How I can create this columns in WPF and handle click on them?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` for that. Create a `CellTemplate` that contains a `Button` whose `Content` is an `Image`, you can style the button to be "invisible" by changing its `Template` to a simple `ContentPresenter`.