# Adding Image in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This is my datagrid i want to display an image in the grid column but its is showing me text `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`, instead of displaying an Image.
How to add an image in a datagrid column?

This is what I have tried :

```
Dictionary dict1=new Dictionary < string,object>();

string keyimage="Image";

object a1 = new BitmapImage();

a1=Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(SystemIcons.Information.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, null);

dict1.Add(keyimage, a1);
```

This `dict1` serves as `Itemsource` for the datagrid...........how to make an image to be displayed in a datagrid column?

Comment: What column type are you using to display an image?

Comment: that was my question..........what column type should i use to display an image?

Comment: What will you have in this dictionary, only Images?

Comment: No not only images.i just want to add a Image column in datagrid in c# code and not in xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and put an image into it.

Since you are using a dictionary, bind the **value**, something like:

```
<Image Binding="{Binding Height="25" Width="50" Source="{Binding Value}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your Column datatype mismatches with itemsource datatype. You have to make equal datatype Image for both Grid Column and itemsource.
In my WPF project I made my column data template with Images:

```
DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
dtab.Columns.Add("imageColumn", typeof(BitmapImage)); 
//Uploading dtab with Images from DataBase

FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
Binding bind = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("imageColumn");
factory.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, bind);
DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = factory };
DataGridTemplateColumn imgCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn() 
{
  Header="image",
  CellTemplate = cellTemplate
};
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.Columns.Add(imgCol);
dg.ItemsSource = dtab.DefaultView;
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Add any image to your Project on Resource folder

After that try the below coding in DataGrid Bind event. Here i have add the image logo...

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imageColoumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        imageColoumn.HeaderText = "Img";
        imageColoumn.Image = null;
        imageColoumn.Name = "DataPic";
        imageColoumn.Width = 150;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColoumn);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewImageCell;
            cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.logo;
        }
```

Comment: DataGridViewImageColumn does it have any namespace or something and more over i am using wpf datagrid and not datagridview

Comment: ok then you just try this link.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938779/image-column-in-wpf-datagrid...

Comment: i have set AutoGenerateColumns="True" since i have a very good dataset and i could easily bind it with the datagrid but now i am trying to add a image in the dataset which the datadrid is not showing......no changes in xaml only thing i could do is to do something in c# code ..........