# Display an image in a DataGrid-Column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to display an image in a DataGrid-Column next to other data.
My model looks like this:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
           return this.persons;
        }

        set
        {
            this.persons = value;
        }
    }
```

And my DataGrid is this:

```
<DataGrid Name="Persons"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Margin="10"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="120"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="120"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Address}"
                                Header="Address" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The Name and Adress get displayed correctly, but the image is empty...
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: Your question is the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938779/image-column-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: use `<Image Source="{Binding Image}" />`

Comment: @xeraphim, is `Image` of a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` type? If yes can you change it to use [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @dkozl thanks for your hint, i created a Dto for Persons because i cant change the type of the original model, but it still doesnt show up :(

Comment: @dkozl i was wrong, it works now :D thanks! if you could do an answer instead of a comment, i'll set it as accepted answer :) thanks!

Comment: @xeraphim [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952174/display-an-image-in-a-datagrid-column/23952617#23952617) added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Image` is of a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` you should change it to [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then change also `Image.Source` binding which at the moment binds to whole `Person` object to its `Image` property

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. It shows the path of the image location instead. Would you suggest any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use that code to display your image :

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
            </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: hey moiz thanks for your answer, but the images still don't show up... in the designer, a hint "cannot resolve property image in data context..." is shown..

Comment: could you please show an example of person image set

Answer (score 0):

Add image floder in your project and add your images in the same folder. use following code to access

```
<Columns> 
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat ="server" CommandName="Preview" ImageUrl="~/images/MSWord_Icon.jpg"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</Columns>
```

Comment: I believe s/he's using WPF, not ASP.NET ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some Height and Width for the image like

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
```

Comment: hey harjeet i tried to set the height and width but it still doesnt show the images :(

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Converters"
<Window.Resource>
 <converter:BindableConverter x:Key="bindableConverter"/>
</Window.Resource>    
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="HeaderName">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image x:Name="BindImg" Height="35" Width="35" Source="{Binding IsBindable,Converter={StaticResource bindableConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                             
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn> 


 public class BindableConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string imageSource = string.Empty;
            bool isBinded;
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
            {
                imageSource = "../../Resource/Images/unbinded.jpg";
            }
            if (Boolean.TryParse(value.ToString(), out isBinded))
            {
                if (isBinded)
                {
                    imageSource = "../../Resource/Images/binded.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    imageSource = "../../Resource/Images/unbinded.jpg";
                }
            }
            return imageSource;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```