# Inserting Images to a Grid in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I found lots of tutorials on how to add things to a grid manually in the XAML file, but the grid I am making is a 15x15 monster that needs to have over 100 images inserted into it.  I was hoping there was some accessor that would allow me to add an image to it in the code-behind file using a loop.

```
<Grid Name="ScrabbleBoard">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create a user control with an image, and inside your for loop place the image inside a canvas.

Comment: yes but how do I add that to the grid.  I can do that manually, but I can't figure out what the code for it is in the code-behind.

Comment: Pls check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938779/image-column-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Grid::Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to add the image element. Then set element's row and column using [Grid.SetRow(element, rowIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190424%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) / [element.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Grid.SetColumn(element, columnIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190650%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) / [element.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ScrabbleBoard.RowDefinitions.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < ScrabbleBoard.ColumnDefinitions.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        var imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourProjectName;component/YourImagesFolderName/YourImageName.jpg"));
        var image = new Image { Source = imageSource };
        Grid.SetRow(image, rowIndex);
        Grid.SetColumn(image, columnIndex);
        ScrabbleBoard.Children.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your not spanning or controlling width/height, it would be simpler to use a uniform grid control. That adds children to the next cell so can be done with a foreach loop over your image collection.